# Firebase Hosting NodeJS Express App not working, times out a lot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I have my big NodeJS app using Firebase, it was last modified in 2018. Since at that time i was learning firebase and firebase hosting from examples. index.js file kinda became huge, it contains routes as well as definitions of Firebase Functions. Currently i wanted to modularize it. So proceeded to upgrade Firebase and dependencies. Something new i had noticied is Firebase Emulators, currently `firebase server` command is not working. `Firebase emulator:start` seems to start the app but mostly times out like out of 30 attempts only once it works.

Version info
Firebase : 11.5.0

Below is the package.json in functions folder.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.6.8",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Below is the firebase.json, emulator key/value is the new one, rest all i had from 2018 and no changes.

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    }
  }
}
```

After i do the `firebase emulators:start`

In the browser, i am getting

```
Timed out waiting for function to respond.
```

In the firebase-debug.log, i see below messages. It says BUSY at multiple places but not sure whats BUSY as it being run locally.

```
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.602Z] [work-queue] {"queueLength":1,"workRunningCount":0}
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.602Z] [work-queue] {"queueLength":0,"workRunningCount":1}
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.602Z] Accepted request GET /prj-out22-20180718/us-central1/app/ --> us-central1-app
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.626Z] [worker-pool] addWorker(us-central1-app) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[worker-pool] addWorker(us-central1-app)"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.627Z] [worker-pool] Adding worker with key us-central1-app, total=2 {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[worker-pool] Adding worker with key us-central1-app, total=2"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.627Z] [worker-pool] submitWork(triggerId=us-central1-app) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[worker-pool] submitWork(triggerId=us-central1-app)"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T05:47:37.628Z] [worker-us-central1-app-37b679fa-3191-43c2-9b15-aad75042f00c]: BUSY {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[worker-us-central1-app-37b679fa-3191-43c2-9b15-aad75042f00c]: BUSY"}}
[debug] FirebaseError: Failed to load function.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsRuntimeWorker.js:104:24)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":{"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"exit":1,"message":"Failed to load function.","status":500}}}
```

And when it works, i see below

```
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:11.950Z] [worker-us-central1-app-873dbf58-beeb-4662-bbc0-23271dfe56e0]: BUSY {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[worker-us-central1-app-873dbf58-beeb-4662-bbc0-23271dfe56e0]: BUSY"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:16.977Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-admin {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"10.3.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-admin {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"10.3.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-admin\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:16.980Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.22.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"3.22.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-functions\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:16.981Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Found local functions config: D:\BigData\13. Firebase\FB-BTD\kickbear\functions/.runtimeconfig.json {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Found local functions config: D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions/.runtimeconfig.json"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:16.981Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Outgoing network have been stubbed. [{"name":"http","status":"mocked"},{"name":"http","status":"mocked"},{"name":"https","status":"mocked"},{"name":"https","status":"mocked"},{"name":"net","status":"mocked"}] {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Outgoing network have been stubbed. [{\"name\":\"http\",\"status\":\"mocked\"},{\"name\":\"http\",\"status\":\"mocked\"},{\"name\":\"https\",\"status\":\"mocked\"},{\"name\":\"https\",\"status\":\"mocked\"},{\"name\":\"net\",\"status\":\"mocked\"}]"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:16.984Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.22.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"3.22.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-functions\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.175Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Checked functions.config() {"config":{}} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Checked functions.config() {\"config\":{}}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.175Z] [runtime-status] [13808] firebase-functions has been stubbed. {"functionsResolution":{"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.22.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js"}} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] firebase-functions has been stubbed. {\"functionsResolution\":{\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"3.22.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-functions\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.178Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.22.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"3.22.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-functions\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.183Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-admin {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"10.3.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-admin {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"10.3.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-admin\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.186Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"3.22.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\index.js"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Resolved module firebase-functions {\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"3.22.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-functions\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.186Z] [runtime-status] [13808] firebase-admin has been stubbed. {"adminResolution":{"declared":true,"installed":true,"version":"10.3.0","resolution":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions\\node_modules\\firebase-admin\\lib\\index.js"}} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] firebase-admin has been stubbed. {\"adminResolution\":{\"declared\":true,\"installed\":true,\"version\":\"10.3.0\",\"resolution\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\\\\node_modules\\\\firebase-admin\\\\lib\\\\index.js\"}}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:17.187Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Functions runtime initialized. {"cwd":"D:\\BigData\\13. Firebase\\FB-BTD\\kickbear\\functions","node_version":"16.16.0"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Functions runtime initialized. {\"cwd\":\"D:\\\\BigData\\\\13. Firebase\\\\FB-BTD\\\\kickbear\\\\functions\",\"node_version\":\"16.16.0\"}"}}
[warn] !  It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().firebase but there is no value there. You can learn more about setting up config here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().firebase but there is no value there. You can learn more about setting up config here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.528Z] [runtime-status] [13808] initializeApp(DEFAULT) {"storageBucket":"prj-out22-20180718.appspot.com","databaseURL":"http://localhost:9000/?ns=prj-out22-20180718","projectId":"prj-out22-20180718"} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] initializeApp(DEFAULT) {\"storageBucket\":\"prj-out22-20180718.appspot.com\",\"databaseURL\":\"http://localhost:9000/?ns=prj-out22-20180718\",\"projectId\":\"prj-out22-20180718\"}"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.812Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Beginning invocation function app! {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Beginning invocation function app!"}}
[info] i  functions: Beginning execution of "app" {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"Beginning execution of \"app\""}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.814Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Running app in signature http {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Running app in signature http"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.834Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Listening to port: \\?\pipe\fire_emu_c5878ff69629ce9a {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Listening to port: \\\\?\\pipe\\fire_emu_c5878ff69629ce9a"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.950Z] [functions] Runtime ready! Sending request! {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[functions] Runtime ready! Sending request!"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.951Z] [functions] Got req.url=/prj-out22-20180718/us-central1/app/, mapping to path=/ {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[functions] Got req.url=/prj-out22-20180718/us-central1/app/, mapping to path=/"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.957Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Ephemeral server handling GET request {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Ephemeral server handling GET request"}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:18.963Z] [runtime-status] [13808] Ephemeral server survived. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-app"},"extension":{},"message":"[runtime-status] [13808] Ephemeral server survived."}}
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:19.597Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET http://localhost:5001/prj-out22-20180718/us-central1/app/ 200
[debug] [2022-08-10T06:05:19.597Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET http://localhost:5001/prj-out22-20180718/us-central1/app/ [stream]
```

Please advise, if any dependencies need to be upgraded to downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this for nearly two days. So i did couple of things.

1. Uninstalled all the NPM Packages which i had installed globally and locally.
2. Reinstalled Firebase-admin, Firebase-Functions and also other packages which was outdated with @latest, locally in the app folder.
3. Was not sure if firebase-tools package is to be installed locally or globally as a standard as Google Docs has global keyword in and one of David Easts recent video he has installed it locally. But anyhow reinstalled globally.

Not much actually changed in my code.

Just restarted the computer all worked.

Update : There seem to be a known [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4807). Downgraded to 11.2.2